# Unable to get the JSON value from select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using select2 dynamic

Using the below code the inside values are treated as string

I am getting {"rooms":["Aerary,false"]} (WRONG)

Expected is: {"rooms":["Aerary",false]} (CORRECT)

Here is the what I have tried with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  <label for="rooms"><b>Choose rooms</b></label>
  <select id="rooms" name="rooms" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select rooms..."></select>
  
  
<script>
var rooms = [{
    "id": ["Aerary", false],
    "text": "Aerary"
}]

$("#rooms").select2({
            data: rooms,
            placeholder: " Click here to select",
        });


function send()
{
        var v = $('#rooms').select2().val();
        if (!v.length) {
            alert("Select rooms");
            return false;
        }
        var data = {
            "rooms": v,
        }
        document.write(JSON.stringify(data) + '<br/><br/>Expected is: ' + JSON.stringify({"rooms":["Aerary", false]}) )

}

</script>

  <button onclick="send()">SEND</button>
  
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting {"rooms":["Aerary,false"]}

Expected is: {"rooms":["Aerary",false]}

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Yes not the same, I want the expected result as answer.

Comment: There is no difference between the `expected` and `wrong` OR am i missing something

Comment: ["Aerary,false"] is different from ["Aerary",false]

Comment: Yeah in your comment its different but not in the question - please check

Comment: Please could you check now again?

Comment: The answer you selected below => false becomes a string as well like "false" - is that what you wanted or want a boolean `false` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lays in how you are setting the value of for the options. As you can see from the example below, the value of created option (logged onto console) is `"Aerary,false"`.

```js
var rooms = [{
  "id": ["Aerary", false],
  "text": "Aerary"
}]

$("#rooms").select2({
  data: rooms,
  placeholder: " Click here to select",
});

console.log(document.querySelector("#rooms").firstChild)
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<label for="rooms"><b>Choose rooms</b></label>
<select id="rooms" name="rooms" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select rooms..."></select>
```

That is because you cannot set multiple values for the value field. What the library does is it calls the `.toString()` function on your object if it's not a string already.

Since the result of a `.toString()` function called on an array is a comma separated list of elements, that's exactly the result that you are getting.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({rooms: [["Aerary",false].toString()]}))
```

In order to handle that you will have to manually parse it, like so:

```
const checkBoolean = (val) => val === "false" ? false : val === "true" ? true: val;
var v = $('#rooms').select2().val().map(el => el.split(",").map(checkBoolean));
```

Just be careful that there are no additional commas within the string.